# Animated cursor made using Framer motion keep disappearing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-animations, framer-motion

I am building a portfolio site using nextjs + tailwindcss and framer motion for animations.

I have implemented a custom animated cursor using framer motion, this works fine but after a few minutes of reloading it keeps disappearing for no reason. Here is a video:

https://www.loom.com/share/84b2bbe766e14e938632b944578d4132

I am able to fix this issue by downgrading the framer-motion version to an older one (v5.3.2), but it has some other bugs with React v18, so I can't downgrade to that version.

I cannot figure out why this keeps disappearing and reappearing, and I can't reproduce this bug at will.

This is my custom mouse component:

```
    <motion.div
          variants={variants}
          animate={cursorContext?.cursorVariant}
          className={`h-5 w-5 rounded-full fixed top-[50vh] left-[50vw] pointer-events- 
          none z-[999] mix-blend-difference ${showCursor ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}
   />
```

Here are my variants:

```
const variants = {
    regular: {
      x: cursorContext!.mousePosition.x - 5,
      y: cursorContext!.mousePosition.y - 5,
      border: "white 2px solid",
    },

    clickable: {
      x: cursorContext!.mousePosition.x - 5,
      y: cursorContext!.mousePosition.y - 5,
      border: 'none',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
    },

    largeClickable: {
      x: cursorContext!.mousePosition.x - 10,
      y: cursorContext!.mousePosition.y - 10,
      border: 'none',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
    },
  };
```

Here are all of my installed packages:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.15",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.